# Mostrar mensaje si no me aparecen registros php

Tags: php, mysql

El problemas que presento es el siguiente, ya que estoy tratando de que cuando busque algo me muestre lo que estoy buscando pero si no encuentra nada entonces muestra un mensaje de no existe, la cuestion es que ya me muestra el mensaje de existe, pero no me muestra el de no existe

Este es el codigo

```
    <?php
    include "mysqlcon.php";
    $con = connect();
    if(isset($_POST['opcion']) && isset($_POST['datos'])){
    $opcion = $_POST['opcion'];
    $datos = $_POST['datos'];
        if ($opcion == 1) {
      $consulta = "SELECT * FROM info WHERE cedula = $datos"; 
    }
    if($opcion == 2){
      $consulta = "SELECT * FROM info WHERE telefono = $datos"; 
    }
    $resultado = mysqli_query($con, $consulta);
    $contador = 0;
    while ($misdatos = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado));
    if (mysqli_num_rows($resultado)>0)
      {
      echo(" Exite registro");
      } else {
      echo("No Existen registros");
      }
}
?>
```

Que estoy omitiendo o en donde esta mi error.

Gracias por la ayuda!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El metodo para contar el numero de registros `mysqli_num_rows` va fuera del while, de esta forma:

```
if (mysqli_num_rows($resultado)>0)
{
   echo(" Exite registro");
   // despues de verificar que si hay registro recorres el objeto
   while ($misdatos = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado))
   {
       // imprimes los registros
   }
} else {
   echo("No Existen registros");
}
```

Comment: Muchas Gracias, dure toda la mañana sufriendo por eso!!!!

Comment: que bien que te funcionó